# PHP File Upload

Tags: php

I'm looking to change my normal PHP file upload into a multiple file upload.

I have this as my single file input:

```
<input name="sliderfile" id="sliderfile" type="file" />
```

And this is the PHP I'm using to upload to my server/place in folder and register it into my databases:

```
if($_POST[sliderurl]){
$path= "uploads/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['sliderfile']['name'];
if($ufile !=none){
if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['sliderfile']['tmp_name'], $path)){
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$added = date("F j, Y");
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `slider` (`imgurl`, `url`, `title`, `description`, `added`) VALUES ('$path', '$_POST[sliderurl]', '$_POST[slidertitle]', '$_POST[sliderdesc]', '$added')");
?>
<div id="fademessage" style="margin-top: 13px;">
<p class="message_greenadmin">Your slide has been successfully created and added to the homepage, Thank you.</p>
</div>
<?php
}else{
?>
<div id="fademessage" style="margin-top: 13px;">
<p class="message_redadmin">Something seems to have gone wrong. Try renaming the photos file name.</p>
</div>
<?php
}
}
}else{
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Escape your data you use in `INSERT` query!

Comment: We're looking to figure out exactly what your question is...

Comment: I was wondering how to make this a multiple file uploader. The INPUT at the moment only let's you select one file, and then I assumed I would need something like a while statement to process or the selected files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need use [move_uploaded_file()](http://tr.php.net/manual/tr/function.move-uploaded-file.php) for save uploaded file. And

```
 foreach ($_FILES['sliderfile'] as $example) {
 UploadFile($example);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I think this may work. Name each input the same with brackets (sliderfile[]) and then loop through them.

```
 foreach ($_FILES['sliderfile'] AS $file) {
 UploadFile($file);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function to upload file

```
    function uploadImage($fileName,$filePath,$allowedList,$errorLocation){
    
      $img = $_FILES[$fileName];
      $imgName =$_FILES[$fileName]['name'];
      $imgTempName = $_FILES[$fileName]['tmp_name'];
      $imgSize = $_FILES[$fileName]['size'];
      $imgError= $_FILES[$fileName]['error'];
    
      $fileExt = explode(".",$imgName);
      $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    
      $allowed = $allowedList;
    
      if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if($imgError == 0){
          
   foreach ($imgTempName as $example) {
      $GLOBALS['fileNameNew']='yourname'.uniqid('',true).".".$fileActualExt;
      $fileDestination = $filePath.$GLOBALS['fileNameNew'];
      $resultsImage = move_uploaded_file($example,$fileDestination);
 }
            
    
          }
          else{
            header('location:'.$errorLocation.'&imgerror');
            exit();
          }
      }
      else{
        header('location:'.$errorLocation.'&extensionError&'.$fileActualExt);
        exit();
      }
    }
```